# Zend Framework: How to set global(town) variables?

Tags: zend-framework, global-variables

I have web-site (for example shops catalog) with several towns. If User select his town i should display him only shop in his town(set global variable for all site?), and give controls to create new shops only in this town and mane-many more functions but only in this town. What better way to declare this global variable?

P.S. Question two - What better solution(fastest, mbe cgi script?) to declare this variable from his IP-address?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For storing global variables in Zend Framework application you can use Zend_Registry:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.registry.using.html

> A registry is a container for storing
>   objects and values in the application
>   space. By storing the value in a
>   registry, the same object is always
>   available throughout your application.
>   This mechanism is an alternative to
>   using global storage.

I guess you could also implement session mechanism for that using Zend_Session:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.html

And more genrically you could create cookie in the user's browser that would remember the town. 
ZF can also handle cookies:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.http.cookies.html

Comment: thx. But what about identify user town automatically from ip?

Comment: that's the new subject ;) That's what geolocation is for ;) There are some free (or cheap) geolocation databases that will translate the IP to country or city